# How to use custom DataSource in ExoPlayer 2?

Tags: android, datasource, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

```
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
    Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri,
    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
player.prepare(videoSource);
```

How can i use custom datasource or AesCipherDataSource in ExoPlayer 2. I tried searching in google, but no solution at all

Answer (score 0):

To use `AesCipherDataSource` you need to implement the library `datasource` from [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/datasource) or [media3](https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/libraries/datasource) depending if you have done the migration or not

```
#For Exoplayer
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"

# For Media3
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-datasource:$media3_version"
```